# Increase in app size on adding mlkit in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-mlkit

I recently added mlkit in my app for smile detection and then .abb size increased from 48mb to 185mb. How can i reduce this size...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a flutter plugin or a direct ML Kit dependency.  You could try use app bundle to include only one arch in your app, or use dynamic feature to download the feature. If you could depends on Google Play Service, you could use the unbundled version which is only hundreds of KB in size: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection/android

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/tips/reduce-app-size to reduce your size of the android app. Also, 48MiB to 185MiB doesn't sounds right. The native android sdk is about ~20MiB even without any of the above optimization.