# flutter google ml kit android APK size reduce solution

Tags: flutter, face-recognition, face-detection, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I would like to ask for a little help here, so for our application there is this feature of face detection and for its implementation we have used google ml kit, but the problem we are facing with that is, it generates the huge APK file size, I would really appreciate your help here if you have got some alternatives for the same, if not the alternative can u please let us know the way around it so that the APK size would not be this big. Thank you!

we are developing a flutter app, plugin reference is from https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_kit

Comment: Have you tried the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68199931/increase-in-app-size-on-adding-mlkit-in-flutter